# How to parse returned php data

Tags: php, arrays

I am accessing an external PHP server feed (not a real link):

```
$raw = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/getResults.php');
```

that returns data in the following context:

```
<pre>Array   
(   
    [RequestResult] => Array   
        (   
            [Response] => Success   
            [Value] => 100
            [Name] => Abracadabra
        )   
)   
</pre>
```

But I can't figure out how to handle this response...  I would like to be able to grab the [Value] value and the [Name] value but my PHP skills are pretty weak... Additionally if there is a way to handle this with JavaScript (I'm a little better with JavaScript) then I could consider building my routine as a client side function...

Can anyone suggest a way to handle this feed response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this

```
function responseToArray($raw)
{
   $result = array();

  foreach(explode("\n", $raw) as $line)
  {
    $line = trim($line);
    if(stripos($line, " => ") === false)
    {
      continue;
    }
    $toks = explode(' => ', $line);
    $k = str_replace(array('[',']'), "", $toks[0]);
    $result[$k] = $toks[1]; 


  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to display correctly when I do a foreach loop, but can't get the value when calling it directly:

example: 

$data = responseToArray($raw);
print $data['Name'];

What did I miss?

Comment: what do you get for `print_r($data)` ?  (I'm flying blind here!)

Comment: This is what I see:

Array ( [ [RequestResult]] => Array [ [Response]] => Success [ [Value]] => IP... ect...

Comment: Did you get the version with the `str_replace` call to remove the square brackets?  Also, you might need to trim `$k`.

Comment: Yeah, that was it... I missed your update...  Works now, thank you...  I will add the trim to $k for good measure...

Comment: Any chance you could convert this into a JavaScript function?

Comment: Post that as a different question.  You can use the snip if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The script on the other side can return a JSON string of the array, and your client script can easily read it. See `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`. http://www.php.net/json-encode and http://www.php.net/json-decode

What you are doing on the "server" script is actually to `var_dump` the variable. `var_dump` is actually used more for debugging to see what a variable actually contains, not for data transfer.

On server script:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$arr_to_output = array();

// ..  fill up array

echo json_encode($arr_to_output);

?>
```

The output of the script would be something like `['element1', 'element2']`.

On client script:

```
<?php

$raw = file_get_contents('http://example.com/getData.php');

$arr = json_decode($raw, true); // true to make sure it returns array. else it will return object.

?>
```

### Alternative

If the structure of the data is fixed this way, then you can try to do it dirty using regular expressions.

On client script:

```
<?php

$raw = file_get_contents('http://example.com/getData.php');

$arr = array('RequestResult'=>array());
preg_match('`\[Response\]\s\=\>\s([^\r\n]+)`is',$raw,$m);
$arr['RequestResult']['Response'] = $m[1];
preg_match('`\[Value\]\s\=\>\s([^\r\n]+)`is',$raw,$m);
$arr['RequestResult']['Value'] = $m[1];
preg_match('`\[Name\]\s\=\>\s([^\r\n]+)`is',$raw,$m);
$arr['RequestResult']['Name'] = $m[1];

// $arr is populated as the same structure as the one in the output.

?>
```

Comment: I wish.  I don't have any control of the source, only my consumption of their response...

Comment: Yeah, it's probably written for a custom application...  I am just trying to figure out how to 'extend' the use of the feed...

Comment: How did you display the output?  print $arr['RequestResult']['Name']

Answer (score 0):

does $raw[RequestResult][Value] not work? I think the data is just a nested hash table

Comment: Don't you mean `$raw['RequestResult']['Value']`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

**Solution #1 Change one line at the source:**

It looks like getResults.php is doing a `print_r`. If that `print_r` could be changed to `var_export` you would get a PHP-parseable string to feed to `eval`:

```
$raw = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/getResults.php');
$a= eval($raw);
echo($raw['RequestResult']['Value']);
```

Be warned, eval'ing raw data from an external source (then echo()'ing it out) is not very secure

**Solution #2 Parse with a regex:**

```
<?php

$s= <<<EOS
<pre>Array   
(   
    [RequestResult] => Array   
        (   
            [Response] => Success   
            [Value] => 100
            [Name] => Abracadabra
        )   
)   
</pre>
EOS;

if (preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\]\s+=>\s+(.+)/', $s, $m)) {
 print_r(array_combine($m[1], $m[2]));
}

?>
```

And now $a would contain: `$a['Value']==100` and `$a['Name']=='Abracadabra'` etc.

Comment: solution one won't work at all. firstly there are html tags because there are `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Ah, it's too bad nothing can be done at the source ... just one line to change!